# Jquery Go to first tab on click of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a small image. When user click on that image, it would scroll down to the bottom for an expanded view. the expanded image is inside tabs (first tab).

**What I want to do is change tabs when the user click on the small image if the user is not in the first tab** as shown in the image

[image]

I somehow managed to get to the  point  where when user click on the small image it would take him to the enlarged image. using following code
-tabs-

```
    <div class="container prod-tab">
        <div class="row prod-des-row">
            <div class="col-12 ">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                        <a name="top"></a><a class="col-4 nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Layers</a>
                        <a class="col-4 nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Description</a>
                        <a class="col-4 nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Features</a>

                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="~/Images/products/LSerene.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
                        <ul>
                            <b>Features & Benefits</b>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

-small image-

```
<div class="col-6 layerr">
                    <a href="#top"><img class="img-fluid layer-img" src="~/Images/products/LSerene.png" /></a>
                </div>
```

-expanded view-

```
<a name="top">
```

I tried this code but it doesn't show the image

```
$("#topp").click(function () {

    $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
    $("#nav-home-tab").addClass("active");
    $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
    $("#nav-home").addClass("active");

});
```

However lets say if the user is in the third tab and click on the small image. it scrolls down and shows the third tab. **All I want to do is change the tab to first tab on each click of the small image**

Comment: Please post the code you have come up with which handles this.

Comment: I havent come up with any code yet. I'm hoping someone would  suggest a jquery code or something. :)

Comment: apply some `id`s or something to your tabs, then using javascript switch to the correct tab before scrolling down. we kind of need to know how youre "tabs" are structured in order to help...

Comment: @BugWhisperer Sorry I couldnt include tabs code earlier. I just included the tabs code.

Comment: you might also want to show how tabs are being changed from one tab to another

Comment: @BugWhisperer I included the whole code . tabs change using bootstrap. I didn't write any code for changing tabs

Comment: @DanIftinca included a jquery code I tried

Comment: @BugWhisperer  I included a jquery code I tried